# Locked out of windows for no specific reason. 2 hours

Tags: windows, login

[image]

What's going on here? There's been no failed attempts, no other users, There's no other options, and the PC is only ever put to sleep.

I dual boot the system (Kali Linux & Windows 10) and I've been in Kali for a week and not mounted the windows drive at all.

This happened before and it worked after 2 hours, but I'm needing to switch to it now & know every time I reboot this will potentially happen.

I have another a laptop which is using the same microsoft account and similar dual boot setup without problems, so it's not account related. It's a local issue.

Is this bypassable using Kali at all? Could it be to do with the UEFI/secure boot or something in that area?

There's been no interaction with the windows portion and I cannot find any reason elsewhere for this behaviour.

Really at a loss for options

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I cannot even start in Safe mode due to the same login issue.
I need to uninstall an app called **TinyWall** because I think this is preventing me selecting the Forgot PIN option, complains of no internet.

Opted to try a windows reset with files kept, but I'd still like to know the fault for future.

Comment: Is this a business account or personal? Have you checked online on your Microsoft account to see if it reports any issues? There should be security and device dashboards for your Microsoft account that will allow you to see what Microsoft is reporting regarding this issue.

Comment: Personal. There's no odd login attempts and 2FA is enabled. It has to be something on the local system that's causing it.

Comment: What other sign-in options does the system offer and you have tried?

Comment: No other options, just type in PIN and get this message, I tried all recovery options I could last time to no avail.

Comment: If you have PIN set up, that means you also have the option to enter the full password. Please look around on the screen for that choice.

Comment: edited my question ^, I do get that option (didn't see before), then it requires internet, which something is blocking, I'm sure it's the app called tinyWall, resetting windows now.